# Add target group to ECS Fargate task using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-fargate

I have a Fargate task that is invoked from a lambda function. I also have a load balancer which is set to a specific target group, let's say, *tg-x*. I use boto3 to run the aforementioned task. However, I do not use a service as I only need this task to be run manually. Is there anyway I can add the target group to this task, like in a service?

My code:

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    client = boto3.client('ecs')
    response = client.run_task(
        cluster='oops-dev', # name of the cluster
        launchType = 'FARGATE',
        taskDefinition='oops-dev-oops-oops:oops'
        count = 1,
        platformVersion='LATEST',
        networkConfiguration={
            'awsvpcConfiguration': {
                'subnets': [
                    'subnet-oops',
                    'subnet-oops',
                    'subnet-oops'
                ],
                'securityGroups': [
                    'sg-oops'
                ],
                'assignPublicIp': 'ENABLED'
            }
    })

    return str(response)
```

I have checked the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html?highlight=at#ECS.Client.run_task), as well as the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-awsvpcconfiguration.html), but to no avail. I also noticed that even in the web interface, it is not possible to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run_task` is for something that is run to completion and exit. For an ECS task that is supposed to stay running and serve something like a web application behind a load balancer, you need to use `create_service` and pass the appropriate `loadBalancers` settings.